# Saving and displaying data with NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I've saved some input from a UITextField using the following code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:myTextField.text forKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

I'd like to display this saved text on a UILabel in another view controller.

I tried this:

```
  myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
```

but nothing displays. Any help with this would be great. thanks.

Comment: Check your outlets. Maybe `myLabel` or `myTextField` is nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the loading and saving code is correct, so it looks like the problem is something else.

Try this to debug:

```
NSString *aValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
NSLog(@"Value from standardUserDefaults: %@", aValue);

NSLog(@"Label: %@", myLabel);
myLabel.text = aValue;
```

Now you will see if the value retriever from the `NSUserDefaults` is set and if the label is assinged.

Answer (score 3):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myTextField.text forKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

After that use **valueForKey** not `objectForKey`:

```
myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"myTextFieldKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that `myTextField` and `myLabel` aren't nil.